# Elasticache bandwidth usage is low, but bandwidth allowance exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

We recently switched to using Elasticache, and we're seeing some blips on the charts for `Network Bandwidth In Allowance Exceeded`, and for `Network Bandwidth Out Allowance Exceeded`:

[image: charts of bandwidth in and out exceeded]

This is weird because we're not using much bandwidth:

[image: charts of bandwidth usage]

We are using a `cache.t4g.small` instance with cluster mode off and one replica. According to [the pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/), we should be getting "Up to 5 Gigabit" network performance. The charts above are nowhere near that.

So why is our bandwidth getting exceeded? Do I just need to suck it up and pay for a larger instance? If so, that's going to be about 4× more expensive, since the next instance with more bandwidth is a `cache.m6g.large`. Something seems off? Or maybe I can ignore these charts?

Comment: same question here... I tried scale up horizontally, but without success.

Answer (score 4):

This is over 6 months ago, but I just stumbled on the same thing. For anyone coming here later, the answer is on [ElastiCache Troubleshooting Connections page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/TroubleshootingConnections.html#Network-limits) and is summed up by:

> NetworkBandwidthInAllowanceExceeded / NetworkBandwidthOutAllowanceExceeded: Network packets shaped because the throughput exceeded the aggregated bandwidth limit.

> It is important to note that every byte written to the primary node will be replicated to N replicas, N being the number of replicas. Clusters with small node types, multiple replicas, and intensive write requests may not be able to cope with the replication backlog. For such cases, it's a best practice to scale-up (change node type), scale-out (add shards in cluster-mode enabled clusters), reduce the number of replicas, or minimize the number of writes.

Also note that the "up to 5 Gigabit" is in bits (not bytes) and is the "burst bandwidth", (not sure how long a burst can be sustained on a t4g). The baseline bandwidth of a t4g.small is 0.128 Gbps ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/general-purpose-instances.html#general-purpose-network-performance)).

Both you and I are gonna need larger instances.